# Allow url to Content Security Policy on Cordova?

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

I have a Cordova app running on my browser with the following tag in index.html:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src *.<my-ip> 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Where `<my-ip>` is the local address of a [peerjs server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) running on my computer.
The problem is that the app shows the following error in the console when running on a browser:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://<my-ip>/myapp/peerjs/id?ts=16759446841950.6026252467790707&version=1.4.7' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *.<my-ip> 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' ws: 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to connect to 'http://<my-ip>:9000/myapp/peerjs/id?ts=16759446841950.6026252467790707&version=1.4.7' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

How can I fix this Content Security Policy directive so my app is able to connect to this local server?

Answer (score 0):

With *. you are allowing subdomains of , while  itself is not allowed, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#framework-directive-source-list. You might have to add both *. and .

If your app is on https, you might also need to be specific about the scheme to allow http.